# Components not working after pushing on Heroku

Tags: heroku, bootstrap-4, components

I have started to build an app using The SB Admin 2 bootstrap theme (can be found here:https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2). Everything is working fine on my localhost but when I pushed the code to Heroku a lot of components did not show or work.

To make it easier to compare, I have pushed the entire code to another Heroku app on https://testweb55.herokuapp.com/, where you can see the difference with what I see on localhost (similar to https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin-2): the user menu on the upper right hand side does not appear, the side bar does not collapse etc.

Do you know what I need to do to make it work on Heroku?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.